# fitting sub-range on time data in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Let me start by saying that I am working on:

> $ gnuplot --version
>
> gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2

I would like to plot and fit date/time data in gnuplot and have the fit only performed and subsequently displayed on a sub-range of the plot.

Example data that I played with can e.g. be found [here](https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadcrut4/data/current/time_series/HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg_smooth.txt).
**EDIT**: I realized that the data in the file don't match the `timefmt` signature, I added a `/06` to each line so that the point would be drawn in the middle of the year which allowed to nicely plot it together with also monthly data from the same source.

I can get the desired result with the code below where I plot three functions, one over the full range of the plot and two others both of which only cover part of the date range.

```
set key left
set yrange[-0.75:1.0]
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y/%m'
r=10e-10
e(x) = r*x+s
fit e(x) 'HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg_smooth.txt' using 1:2 via r,s
a=10e-10
f(x) = a * x + b
set xrange ["1970/06":"2018/06"]
fit f(x) 'HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg_smooth.txt' using 1:2 via a,b
g(x) = ( x > "1970/06" ) ? f(x) : 1/0
set xrange ["1850/06":"1970/06"]
c=9.24859e-11
h(x) = c * x + d
fit h(x) 'HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg_smooth.txt' using 1:2 via c,d
i(x) = ( x < "1970/06" ) ? h(x) : 1/0
set xrange ["1849/06":"2018/06"]
set term png size 1500,1000
set output 'annual_average_with_fit.png'
plot 'HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg_smooth.txt' using 1:2 with lp lw 2 t'annual avg (decadally smoothed)', e(x) t'full range fit' lw 2, i(x) t'1850-1970 fit' lw 2, g(x) t'1970-2018 fit' lw 2
```

which yields this plot

[image]

This is all good and well, but (and this is where the question comes in) in principle I should be able to achieve the same result also by other means.

First: I restrict the range of the file data to a certain range to fit it only on that range. In principle I should be able to do the same using this (type of) syntax:

```
fit ["1970/06":"2018/06"] f(x) 'HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg_smooth.txt' using 1:2 via a,b
```

which however gives

> Read 168 points
>
> Skipped 168 points outside range [x=1970:2018]
>
> [...] No data to fit

which seems weird given that the `set xrange` clearly has the desired effect.

Secondly trying to restrict the plotting of the curve to the fit range with

```
plot 'HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg_smooth.txt' using 1:2 with lp lw 2 t'annual avg (decadally smoothed)', ["1970/06":"2018/06"] f(x) t''
```

does not plot the function at all.

I might be overlooking something very basic, but having tried various things I don't see what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following (a bit cleaned up) code should do what you want (tested with gnuplot 5.2.5).
I guess the problem is that you tried to fit a range `["1970/06":"2018/06"]`, but your data is only until 2017. So better leave it open, e.g.  `["1970/06":]` or `["1970/06":*]`.

edit: added a limited range fit i(x)

```
reset session
set term png size 1500,1000
set output 'annual_average_with_fit.png'

set key left
set yrange[-0.75:1.0]
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y/%m'
set format x '%Y'

FILE = 'HadCRUT.4.6.0.0.annual_ns_avg_smooth.txt'

r=10e-10
f(x) = r*x+s
fit [*:*] f(x) FILE using 1:2 via r,s

c=9.24859e-11
g(x) = c * x + d
fit [*:"1970/06"] g(x) FILE using 1:2 via c,d

a=10e-10
h(x) = a * x + b
fit ["1970/06":*]  h(x) FILE using 1:2 via a,b

p=1e-9
i(x) = p * x + q
fit [strptime("%Y/%m", "1910/06"):strptime("%Y/%m", "1945/06")] i(x) FILE using 1:2 via p,q

set xrange [*:*]
plot FILE using 1:2 with lp lw 2 t'annual avg (decadally smoothed)', \
    f(x) t 'full range fit' lw 2, \
    [:"1970/06"] g(x) t '1850-1970 fit' lw 2, \
    ["1970/06":] h(x) t '1970-2018 fit' lw 2,\
    [strptime("%Y/%m", "1910/06"):strptime("%Y/%m", "1945/06")] i(x) t '1910-1945 fit' lw 2

set output
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: The code indeed does what I want with the specified commands and clearly is cleaner than mine, so I'll accept the answer. Your conjecture about the range is not completely true though, if I select "2016/06" as upper limit, which is clearly inside the range, I get the same error. Thus for my particular example the open ranges work fine, but I guess my next question would be how to e.g. perform three fits where the middle one obviously is bound on both sides

Comment: you're right. I didn't expect this and I cannot explain why it doesn't work with a both side limited range. Well, but e.g. with `[strptime("%Y/%m", "1910/06"):strptime("%Y/%m", "1945/06")]` it seems to work. I added this to the code above.